# Pass parameters from ComboBox to GTKTreeView in C

Tags: c, combobox, gtk3, gtktreeview

In C Language, how is it possible to pass the values in ComboBox to GtkTreeView? We have tried this code, but we do not know where to write the ids of ComboBox. What signals should be used in ComboBox?

```
   void on_btn_car_order_clicked(GtkButton *button, gpointer *user_data){
    GtkTreeIter iter;

    GtkTreeView *treeview_payment1 = GTK_TREE_VIEW(user_data);
    GtkListStore *liststore1 = GTK_LIST_STORE(gtk_tree_view_get_model(treeview_payment1));
    gtk_list_store_append(liststore1, &iter);
    gtk_list_store_set(liststore1, &iter, 0, "asdas" , 1, 1.0,2, 10.0, -1);    
    gtk_widget_hide (GTK_WIDGET(detail_window));
    gtk_widget_show(listree_window);     
}
```

[GtkTreeView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWarc.png)
[GtkWindow with ComboBox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QL0j.png)

Thank you,
Best regards,
Shak

Comment: A more detailed explanation of your requirement would be helpful.. Like when you want to pass combo box to treeview ??

Comment: If you have a look in this picture (GtkWindow with ComboBox), you can see a button "Order". on_btn_car_order_clicked

We tried passing the value in ComBox to Label and it works.

Comment: so on pressing order, you want to pass the data to the treeView and fill the table.If possible could you share your code.. it will be easier for me to suggest the changes.

Comment: Where can I send you my code, I dont think it will fit here..

Comment: You could upload it in some online cloud storage site and give me permission to edit it.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=15yGSCFDBU1qaEIaJ7pqN-R8TfDGdIiqj

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

typedef struct
{
    GtkWidget *w_car_choose;
    GtkWidget *w_model_choose;
    GtkWidget *w_submit_button;
    GtkWidget *w_treeview;
} app_widgets;

GtkBuilder *builder;
GtkWidget *main_window;
GtkWidget *listtree_window;

void on_btn_submit_clicked(GtkButton *button, gpointer *user_data);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    app_widgets *widgets = g_slice_new(app_widgets);

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    builder = gtk_builder_new();
    gtk_builder_add_from_file(builder, "test.glade", NULL);

    main_window = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "main_window"));
    listtree_window = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "listtree_window"));


    // get pointers to widgets
    widgets->w_treeview = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "treeview"));
    widgets->w_car_choose = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "car_choose"));
    widgets->w_model_choose = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "model_choose"));
    widgets->w_submit_button = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "btn_submit"));
    gtk_combo_box_set_active(GTK_COMBO_BOX(widgets->w_car_choose), 1);
    gtk_combo_box_set_active(GTK_COMBO_BOX(widgets->w_model_choose), 1);

    gtk_builder_connect_signals(builder, widgets);

    g_object_unref(builder);

    gtk_widget_show(main_window);

    g_signal_connect(GTK_WIDGET(widgets->w_submit_button), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(on_btn_submit_clicked), widgets);

    gtk_main();
    g_slice_free(app_widgets, widgets);

    return 0;
}

void on_btn_submit_clicked(GtkButton *button, gpointer *user_data)
{
    app_widgets *widgets = user_data;

    GtkTreeIter iter;
    GtkListStore *liststore = GTK_LIST_STORE(gtk_tree_view_get_model(GTK_TREE_VIEW(widgets->w_treeview)));
    gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &iter);
    gtk_list_store_set(liststore, &iter, 0, gtk_combo_box_text_get_active_text(GTK_COMBO_BOX(widgets->w_model_choose)), 1, gtk_combo_box_text_get_active_text(GTK_COMBO_BOX(widgets->w_car_choose)), -1);

    gtk_widget_hide(GTK_WIDGET(main_window));
    gtk_widget_show(listtree_window);
}

// called when window is closed
void on_window_main_destroy()
{
    gtk_main_quit();
}
```

if you want to pass customized data during onClick signal then connect using

```
g_signal_connect
```

https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-Signals.html. 
and generally, for connecting signals, you can manually connect it using g_connect as mostly during your program you might want to modify data's which will be stored in your struct so instead of using glade for it, you can manually connect.

#suggestions(if your actual program is gonna look like this). you could finish the above program in a single main window by adding an Add button to "listtree_window" window and making "main_window" a dialog box.

Comment: in your glade file remove "onclick" handler for submit button

Comment: int i = 0;

 char *p = strtok (car_name, " ");
 char *data[100];

 while (p)
 {
       data[i++] = p;
       p = strtok (NULL, " ");
 } 

printf("PRINT VALUE FROM DATA[0]: %s\n", data[0]);

gtk_list_store_set(liststore1, &iter, 0,  data[0], 1, data[1], 2, data[2], 3,  data[3], 4, data[4], 5, data[5], 6,  data[6], 7, data[7], 8, data[8], 9,  data[9], 10, data[10], -1);

[rintf is working, while, gtk_list_store_set is not working. How can I fix this?

Comment: (https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-String-Utility-Functions.html#g-strdup-printf) try using Glib string utility functions. strtok() is inherently unsafe   (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8957829/strtok-segmentation-fault)